# A system of two multivariable coupled ODEs

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I'm trying to solve the following problem of coupled ODEs using `odeint()` from scipy. The system looks like this:

> X'_k = mean(Y_k) + F
>
> Y'_{k,j} = X_k - Y_{k,j}

This is a system with 3 X variables, and for each X variable, there are other 3 Y variables.

From what I read from the documentation, and the examples [here](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/CoupledSpringMassSystem.html) and [here](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/LoktaVolterraTutoriald1e1.html), I can pass the system of equations as a list. And that is what I tried in the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def dZdt(Z, t):

    X = Z[0]
    Y = Z[1]

    F = 4

    d_x = np.zeros(3)
    d_y = np.zeros(3*3).reshape(3,3)

    # Compute the Y values
    for k in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            d_y[k][j] = X[k] - Y[k][j]

        # X values
        d_x[k] = Y[k].mean() + F

    d = [d_x, d_y]

    return d

# Initial conditions
X0 = np.random.uniform(size=3)
Y0 = np.random.uniform(size = 3*3).reshape(3,3)
Z0 = [X0, Y0]

t = range(20)

Z = odeint(dZdt, Z0, t)
```

Where k, j = (1,2,3) and Z = [X,Y]

But I'm afraid I'm getting the following error:

`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3)`

My real problem is more complex, because j, and k, can be bigger than 3 (they go from 1 to j_max, and K_max, respectively) so I cannot write the 12 variables one by one.

My guessing is that somewhere in the code, Y variables are tried to fill in X shape... but no clue about where.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to represent an unknown function by two arrays inside of a list. It must be a one-dimensional array. So, instead of 3 X-variables and 9 Y-variables it must be a flat list of 12 variables. Like this:

```
def dZdt(Z, t):

    X = Z[:3]
    Y = Z[3:].reshape(3, 3)
    F = 4

    d_x = np.zeros(3)
    d_y = np.zeros((3, 3))

    # Compute the Y values
    for k in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            d_y[k, j] = X[k] - Y[k, j]

        # X values
        d_x[k] = Y[k].mean() + F

    d = np.concatenate((d_x.ravel(), d_y.ravel()))

    return d

# Initial conditions
X0 = np.random.uniform(size=3)
Y0 = np.random.uniform(size=(3, 3))
Z0 = np.concatenate((X0.ravel(), Y0.ravel()))

t = range(20)

Z = odeint(dZdt, Z0, t)
```

NumPy arrays are indexed as `Y[k, j]`, not `Y[k][j]`. And there are ample vectorization opportunities that would eliminate the loops in the computation of `dZdt`. Like this:

```
def dZdt(Z, t):

    X = Z[:3]
    Y = Z[3:].reshape(3, 3)
    F = 4

    d_y = X[:, None] - Y 
    d_x = Y.mean(axis=1) + F

    d = np.concatenate((d_x.ravel(), d_y.ravel()))

    return d
```